# ionic3 - nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/usr/local"

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic3

This is ionic3 project, after I installed `nvm`, can running without warning. But when I restart my mac and restart VSCode that warning coming out.

> nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently
>   set to "/usr/local" Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v8.6.0 --silent` to unset it.

**nvm --version** 0.33.8

**ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    Node       : v6.11.3
    npm        : 3.10.10
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to VSCode settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": []
```

As discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36987#issuecomment-340147201).

Comment: Thank you so much, don't know why suddenly this waring not showing for my project already

Answer (score 1):

**nvm** will manage **node packages** folder based on installing node. To solve your problem just  delete or unset the "prefix" setting:

> npm config delete prefix

if this not help try to remove the prefix value manually. Edit the "~/.npmrc" file and remove the "prefix" variable.

Comment: I tried to run this command already, but still showing warning for me.

Comment: try to rename existing global package folder which "prefix" point to. Then validate the value of "prefix" is empty with command "npm config get prefix" It must be empty to install a new version of "node" with nvm tool. Otherwise you always get a warning message. I2m interested in value of "npm config get prefix" value. Can you share it?

Comment: you mean reinstall `nvm`?

Comment: when command "npm config get prefix" returns empty value then you should  run nvm tool without any warning. Otherwise check "~/.npmrc file in your user home folder for hard-coded "prefix" variable.

Comment: sure..please change your answers when it works, I will mark it. thank you

Comment: This returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` on Ubuntu 18.04 with npm 8.12.0 installed via `nvm`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error msg in VSC's integrated terminal when running `npm run start`. The error message is displayed as soon as the terminal is loaded, but it doesn't happen on my external terminal (using iTerm2).

I know this happened to me bc I globally installed `npm` using another version of `node`.

To resolve it, I went ahead and looked for the old `npm` folder and removed it.

Find the path by running `which npm` and then find old node_modules to remove by running this: `ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep "np[mx]"`. This will give you two paths, so use these two paths to remove by running the following:

```
rm -R /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
rm -R /usr/local/bin/npx /usr/local/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
```

Restart VSC and open a new terminal to run `npm run start`, and you shouldn't encounter the issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.npmrc` file from root directory. Redefine your custom configuration for node. This time will work!